# Trigger function on close in window.js Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, prototype-js

I am using window.js to show a popup.
In pop up i used a `phtml file`

```
    <div class="hb-giveReview" id="custompopup">
      <a onclick="return showForm('signup_popup_form')" href="#">
       <button class="reviewBtn">Write a Review</button>
      </a> 
   </div>
```

Inside a div, I called `phtml file`

```
<div id="signup_popup_form" style="display: none;" >
<?php  echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')
    ->setTemplate('instagramapi/signupform.phtml')->toHtml();?>
</div>
```

I want to run a function when user click on `close button`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showForm(id){
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "block";
win = new Window({ id:'popup_window', className: "magento", title: "Sign Up Form", zIndex:3000, destroyOnClose: true, recenterAuto:true, resizable: true, width:450, height:473, minimizable: false, maximizable: false, draggable: true});
win.setContent(id, false, false);
win.showCenter();
}
$(document).on('click', '.magento_close', function() {
     alert('letsclose');
})
</script>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: ` alert('letsclose');` it is not triggred

Comment: i want to hide `signupform.phtml` as this form is visible after pop up closed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291712/is-it-possible-to-open-a-popup-with-javascript-and-then-detect-when-the-user-clo  take a look at this

Comment: i am using `window.js` which is included in magento 1.9

Comment: Do you not have access to JQ? Or is that just Prototype JS in your code? Regardless the approach in that answer still holds